# Ubuntu 18.04 desktop won't boot after updates

Tags: boot, 18.04, updates

Yesterday I installed the pending updates on my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. After that I rebooted, and the system would not come up. After several attempts, the result was the same: I could get past grub, but then the boot process froze at this point:

[image]

Following the recommendation of a post I found searching on the last couple of lines of that output, I booted again, replacing the `quiet` boot option with `noapic noacpi`. That got me here:

[image]

Noting the message about 10 lines up from the bottom, I then tried `noapic noacpi acpi=off`. That in turn got me here:

[image]

Having no further hints, I tried a variety of combinations of those options, also trying a few incarnations with `nomodeset`, and still never got significantly farther in the process.

Booting with a previous kernel has the same end result, as does recovery mode. More strangely, booting an old installation of 17.10 on another partition also produced the same result. Finally I was able to boot into my last available already-installed option, which was Xubuntu 16.10. That successfully started, and I was able to fetch the `/var/log/apt/history.log` entries from yesterday in the Ubuntu 18.04 installation:

```
Start-Date: 2020-01-25  09:14:21
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Requested-By: myuser (1000)
Upgrade: 
libcom-err2:amd64 (1.44.1-1ubuntu1.2, 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3), 
libcom-err2:i386 (1.44.1-1ubuntu1.2, 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3), 
libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libegl-mesa0:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.12, 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14), 
libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.14, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15), 
mesa-common-dev:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.1, 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.2), 
libbsd0:amd64 (0.8.7-1, 0.8.7-1ubuntu0.1), 
libbsd0:i386 (0.8.7-1, 0.8.7-1ubuntu0.1), 
e2fsprogs:amd64 (1.44.1-1ubuntu1.2, 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3), 
gnome-software:amd64 (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.12, 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14), 
python-apt-common:amd64 (1.6.4, 1.6.5ubuntu0.2), 
libegl1-mesa:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libgbm1:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
thunderbird-gnome-support:amd64 (1:68.2.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), 
libss2:amd64 (1.44.1-1ubuntu1.2, 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3), 
samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.14, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15), 
libext2fs2:amd64 (1.44.1-1ubuntu1.2, 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3), 
libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
nautilus:amd64 (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.4, 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.5), 
libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.4, 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.5), 
ubuntu-software:amd64 (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.12, 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14), 
gir1.2-snapd-1:amd64 (1.49-0ubuntu0.18.04.0, 1.49-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), 
thunderbird-locale-en-us:amd64 (1:68.2.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), 
libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libgcrypt20:amd64 (1.8.1-4ubuntu1.1, 1.8.1-4ubuntu1.2), 
libgcrypt20:i386 (1.8.1-4ubuntu1.1, 1.8.1-4ubuntu1.2), 
libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
gnome-shell-common:amd64 (3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2, 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3), 
python-apt:amd64 (1.6.4, 1.6.5ubuntu0.2), 
libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libdrm2:i386 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.14, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15), 
aptdaemon-data:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.1, 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.2), 
thunderbird:amd64 (1:68.2.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), 
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
python3-aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.1, 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.2), 
libgnutls30:amd64 (3.5.18-1ubuntu1.2, 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.3), 
libgnutls30:i386 (3.5.18-1ubuntu1.2, 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.3), 
libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
nautilus-data:amd64 (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.4, 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.5), 
gnome-shell:amd64 (3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2, 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3), 
libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libsnapd-glib1:amd64 (1.49-0ubuntu0.18.04.0, 1.49-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), 
aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.1, 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.2), 
libsdl-image1.2:amd64 (1.2.12-8, 1.2.12-8ubuntu0.1), 
gnome-software-common:amd64 (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.12, 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.14), 
libdrm-dev:amd64 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
thunderbird-locale-en:amd64 (1:68.2.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), 
python3-apt:amd64 (1.6.4, 1.6.5ubuntu0.2), 
libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1, 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-01-25  09:15:00

Start-Date: 2020-01-25  09:16:19
Commandline: apt-get upgrade libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers
Requested-By: myuser (1000)
Install: 
libllvm9:amd64 (1:9-2~ubuntu18.04.1, automatic), 
libllvm9:i386 (1:9-2~ubuntu18.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: 
libglapi-mesa:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libglapi-mesa:i386 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libxatracker2:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libosmesa6:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libosmesa6:i386 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
mesa-va-drivers:i386 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libglx-mesa0:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libglx-mesa0:i386 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 19.2.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-01-25  09:16:29
```

The update was done via the command line, and was done in two phases as the second set was kept back.

There were definitely some video related updates, but since I can't actually boot into the OS, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your issue in particular, but i once bricked my machine while installing some nvidia drivers. If i remember i was able to get a recovery bash session going (sometimes you can press ctrl + alt + f1 to f7). Once i was there i removed the bad driver, rebooted, and installed one that worked.

Sorry for not having a clear cut answer.

Comment: Unfortunately those were some of the key combinations I tried... no response at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets first check your file system.**

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB (or your 16.10)
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I was able to mount the filesystem just fine to grab the logs, but I ran `fsck -f` just to be sure. It just found a couple of "inode extent tree could be shorter". Fixing those didn't change anything.

Comment: @glibdud In your BIOS, what are the settings for `Secure Boot` and `Compatibility Support Module (CSM)`?

Comment: I'm using an MSI board (H370) that doesn't even show the secure boot option unless Windows 10 support is enabled, which it isn't. I can't find the CSM option. I have a hard time believing an update would cause an issue with my BIOS settings which have been working fine for a year or so. I do appreciate the effort, though.

Comment: @glibdud Being as your system fails in so many different ways, it sounds like a systemic problem. The `Secure Boot` and `CSM` settings came from a web site where I was researching your problem. In the mean time, either enter your BIOS and see if your BIOS version is 7B16v18, or boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and open `terminal` and type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and see what the BIOS version is. If need be, go to https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/H370-GAMING-PRO-CARBON and download the newer version.

Comment: Status please...